# What is this "defineCall is not a function" error that I am getting?

Tags: sequelize.js

[image]   //This is what is in my "html-routes.js" file:

```
app.get("/game", function(req, res) {
db.Questions.findAll({}).then(function(questions) {
  res.render("game", {
    test: "Yes",
    triviaquestions: "../models/questions.js" // this is the issue I am having
  });
});
console.log('hi');

[![enter image description here][1]][1]});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is often because your `models/index.js`, which (if you're using the generator) tries to automatically import everything in `models`, is pulling in files that aren't Sequelize models. In my case, it was because I had my test files alongside the models, and it was loading those as well. Check there aren't any non-model files in there, or change `models/index.js` to exclude anything that's not a model (like tests).